# how can I filter a collection by smaller time increments?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Given a collection that looks like this:

```
[
{Price:123.45, DateTime:01/01/18 12:01:10}
{Price:89.23, DateTime:01/01/18 12:01:20}
{Price:66.13, DateTime:01/01/18 12:01:30}
{Price:75.00, DateTime:01/01/18 12:02:45}
]
```

How can I filter this collection with linq to only include the first data item which exists closest to the start of each minute?  So for example, I want to transform the collection above into the following collection:

```
[
{Price:123.45, DateTime:01/01/18 12:01:10}
{Price:75.00, DateTime:01/01/18 12:02:45}
]
```

Also, how can I implement a similar solution but instead of filtering the collection to include the first data item closest to the start of each minute, I want to include the first data item closest to the start of each 5 minute interval? For example, the closest data item to 12:00, 12:05, 12:10, etc?

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a free code writing service.

Comment: My LINQ knowledge is limited. But if I wanted to do that with SQL, I would do something like: Make a temporary table/view/select result consisted of: Price, TimeRounded to the second, exact time. Then would group by TimeRounded and get the first time/Price entry.

Comment: Does closest mean before or after, or just after the target time?

Comment: @itsme86 - I'm stumped.  I've been using linq for 10 years but I'm not sure how to go about this

Comment: @Plutonix - for example, if a datapoint falls at 12:01:00 then use that datapoint. if the datapoint falls at 12:01:10 but there were no data points before that then use that datapoint at 12:01:10

Comment: But is `12:01:55` considered closer to `12:02:00` than `12:02:10`?

Comment: Do you have a non-linq solution that's working the way you expect?

Comment: Yes. Can still edit, just a minute. There, edited. I guess I should go to sleep soon, I messed up all the numbers in my original comment....

Comment: Given the sample data, it appears we only want to use values that are greater than or equal to the minute, otherwise `12:01:30` would have been in the results instead of `12:02:45`, since `12:01:30` is closer to `12:02:00`.

Comment: @user8570495 show an attempt up to where you got stuck and the community can help you the rest of the way, but you have to show an effort. They are not just going to write the code for you even if they already know the answer.

Comment: Break the problem down into simpler steps. 1) Group the items by the minute component of the DateTime value, 2) From each group, select the item with the lowest DateTime value (hint: OrderBy().First(), 3) Profit. The grouping part of the second question is trickier, but not horrendously so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution for your first question is:

```
items.GroupBy(x => x.DateTime.AddSeconds(-x.DateTime.Second))
     .Select(x => x.OrderBy(i => i.DateTime).First());
```

Then I tried to make reusable solution that lets you to set any time interval:

```
public static IEnumerable<Item> ClosestTo(IEnumerable<Item> items, TimeSpan interval)
{
    return items.GroupBy(item =>
    {
        // Find a date that is closest to the start of interval.
        var ticksFloor = item.DateTime.Ticks - (item.DateTime.Ticks % interval.Ticks);
        return new DateTime(ticksFloor);
    }).Select(grouping => grouping.OrderBy(item => item.DateTime).First());
}
```

---

Example:

```
var items = new List<Item>
{
    new Item { DateTime = DateTime.Parse("01/01/18 12:01:10") },
    new Item { DateTime = DateTime.Parse("01/01/18 12:01:20") },
    new Item { DateTime = DateTime.Parse("01/01/18 12:01:30") },
    new Item { DateTime = DateTime.Parse("01/01/18 12:02:45") },
    new Item { DateTime = DateTime.Parse("01/01/18 12:05:00") },
    new Item { DateTime = DateTime.Parse("01/01/18 12:07:30") },
    new Item { DateTime = DateTime.Parse("01/01/18 12:09:00") },
    new Item { DateTime = DateTime.Parse("01/01/18 12:14:00") }
};

foreach (var item in ClosestTo(items, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"DateTime: {item.DateTime}");
}
```

The output is:

> DateTime: 01.01.2018 12:01:10
>   DateTime: 01.01.2018 12:05:00
>   DateTime: 01.01.2018 12:14:00